# Using "margin:0 auto;" and background-color without inner div

Tags: css, html

I want a centred block using auto left/right margins, but I also want it to have a background colour. Since background colour is not applied to the margin area of a block, I'm using a block with the background colour set, and then an inner block with the auto margins.

I don't like this, since it requires extraneous markup. Is there a technique to achieve this while just using a single block?

Update: to clarify, I want to achieve the same thing with only one block, not two; in the example below I want to drop the inner div.

Bare bones code I'm using at present:

```
<section id="example">
    <div id="inner">
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p>Example content.</p>
    </div>
</section>

<style>
    #example {
        background-color:#ccc;
    }
    #inner {
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:10px 0;
        width:500px;
        background:white;
    }
</style>
```

Couldn't find anything searching the site or Google.

Thanks in advance,
Nigel

Comment: This is confusing question. You should mock up a jsfiddle.net to explain what the problem is. I can't actually tell what your issue is, despite reading it 5+ times. (Maybe you just want box-sizing)

Comment: As far as I understand, Nigel wants an element less (#inner), but the same visual effect

Comment: Yes, exactly as Martinijn says. I want to achieve the same thing without having to use two blocks. In this case a section and an inner div. Sorry it's not clear, will update the question to clarify.

Comment: @NigelPeck If you using text elements, you can use `text-align:center`, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8REmd/).

Comment: But this way the text wont be aligned left in a centered div.

Comment: As @Layke suggests, your question is not clear and your [demo markup](http://jsfiddle.net/Tbfdm/) isn't particularly effective in communicating a problem. It sounds as if you wish to "color" a margin width that's variable somehow to it's relationship to a parent, without having a parent? If you give a working example, that would probably help a lot.

Comment: Also keep in mind that (at least in HTML5), `div`, `span` and other non-flow elements are [designed for these purposes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html). Whether it is extraneous or not is somewhat in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't know how to make it any clearer. I agree that div is intended for this use, the reason I am saying it is extraneous is that there is already a block there, so it seems extraneous to me to have another as the only child of it, and something that should be achievable in CSS only; namely to have the contents of a block be centred while also having a background colour on that same block. The example I've given is working. I don't care about whether it's the margin that is used or something else, the point is that the contents should be centred.

Comment: Sorry the example wasn't really working. I added some more style to the #inner to clarify.

Comment: Are you talking about like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Tbfdm/1/ (Little bit different example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tbfdm/2/)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, that's it. Blade0rz already suggested that below. It's a nice solution, but I noted my issue with it in response to his answer, perhaps continue discussion there if you have more to say on it?

Comment: My only comment at this point is that you're trimming markup you need to achieve your layout. When you trim the fat, be careful not to hit bone. And if it's semantics (`div`) that bother you, if in the right context, use `blockquote` instead.

Comment: You are using the * selector in css, that will cost you more than the div. Using a * in css is not recommended because its slow. In this case it wont be that bad, only two elements, but 1 div will always be faster :) (again, this scale is too small to notice, but if you would do this site-wide you might)

Comment: @Martijn That's a good point, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want the div#inner to be centered, it will always be in a parent. In this case another element #portfolio, but it could also be body. This solution would be perfectly acceptable.

You could try adding negative margins and some paddings, but you would complicatie things allot. What you have now makes sence to me, one element that fills the width and gives the full a background color, and one element which gets positioned in center

Comment: I also tried `padding: 0 auto;` just for the fun of it, but that does not work. Would've been fun

Comment: Yes tried auto padding too, shame it doesn't work it would be a nice solution. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sorry for second comment, but you make a good point that what I'm using isn't really extraneous, it does make sense that there would be two blocks here. Will chew on that. I just don't like markup that is purely for styling purposes. It seems like this should be achievable with one block.

Comment: Having thought about this, I am accepting this answer. It makes sense to have the outer element.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed set of block elements, you can set the margin on all the children of `#example`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/r5XJM/1/) is a jsFiddle.

Problem is what you save in HTML markup, you waste in CSS and it is under the assumption that you only have block children. Adding, for example, a `<span>` tag would break this flow, they would themselves need to be wrapped in a block container.

**HTML**

```
<section id="example">
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p>Example content.</p>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#example {
        background-color:#ccc;
}
#example > * {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This would work if this is all the content that is ever gonna be here. If he gets more html, he is going to need to rewrite it back to the situation he has now. I like this idea

Comment: Exactly (*If you have a fixed set of block elements*). There is no better solution to what the OP already has in my opinion, just alternatives.

Comment: I like this idea too, although not ideal for the reason you suggest, having to have all the extra css for a potentially long list of types of children.

Comment: @NigelPeck If you can ensure all children will be block elements, which most of the time they will be, you can just use the all selector: `#example > *` - see updated answer & fiddle

Comment: Yes that's a good point. I like that. Although I would still prefer a solution where it was the overall container that did the centring, rather than the children. For example, it would break if I tried to indent one of the children's margins, and just push the problem of having to have an inner div further down. I'm looking for something to use on a regular basis to achieve this.

@Blade0rz Yes I think you're right, although perhaps there's something I've not considered. Thought it was worth putting out there for suggestions.

Comment: Other than setting padding, it's not possible to cover all elements. Perhaps you can set the padding of your `section` and use CSS media queries to cater for different screen sizes.